# Dispatch is not saving data in datalayer in React Context Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm following a tutorial where they are making a clone of Spotify. For that I got the user access token to access all the user data. And to avoid prop-drilling I'm using `React Context-api` to save and pull user data (token, user info, playlist info, etc.). In my `Sidebar.js` I'm want to pull playlist info from the datalayer context and show it to the user. But the playlist info isn't showing there and after console logging, I got `undefined`. To be sure, I also console logged the playlist info in `App.js`, there I'm getting all the information I need but not in the `Sidebar.js`. I've attached the screenshot of what I'm getting in this link --> https://ibb.co/PGj4XcT ,
Any help would be appreciated.

**Sidebar.js**

```
function SideBar() {
  const [{ playlists }, dispatch] = UseDataLayerValue();
  console.log("user playlist from sidebar.js", playlists);

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <img
        className="sidebar__logo"
        src="https://getheavy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/spotify2019-830x350.jpg"
        alt="spotify-logo"
      />
      <SidebarOption Icon={HomeIcon} title="Home" />
      <SidebarOption Icon={SearchIcon} title="Search" />
      <SidebarOption Icon={LibraryMusicIcon} title="Your Library" />
      <br />
      <strong className="sidebar__title">PLAYLISTS</strong>
      <hr />

      {playlists?.items?.map((list) => {
        return <SidebarOption title={list.name} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [{ token }, dispatch] = UseDataLayerValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    const hash = getTokenFromUrl;
    window.location.hash = "";
    const _token = hash.access_token;

    if (_token) {
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_TOKEN",
        token: _token,
      });
      // setToken(_token);

      spotify.setAccessToken(_token);

      spotify.getMe().then((user) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: user,
        });
      });

      spotify.getUserPlaylists().then((playlist) => {
        console.log("user playlist from app.js", playlist);
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_PLAYLIST",
          playlists: playlist,
        });
      });
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  //console.log(user);
  //console.log(token);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {token ? <Player spotify={spotify} /> : <Login />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Reducer.js**

```
export const initialState = {
  user: null,
  playlists: [],
  playing: false,
  item: null,
  token: null,
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_USER":
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
      };
    case "SET_TOKEN":
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.token,
      };
    case "SET_PLAYLIST":
      return {
        ...state,
        playlists: action.playlist,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: There is a typo in your reducer, should be `playlists: action.playlists`

Comment: @BankBuilder but in my `App.js`  I'm getting `playlist` from the promise, ain't I? why playlists? Also in `Sidebar.js` I'm getting the playlist info but the mapping isn't working

Comment: Everything else looks right to me, but your dispatch looks like this: `dispatch({type: "SET_PLAYLIST", playlists: playlist});`. Notice that the key in your action is named `playlists` (as in `action.playlists`), but in your reducer you reference it as `action.playlist`.

Comment: @BankBuilder yeah i got it but still the mapping doesn't work. I console logged each item but they are not being called in `SidebarOption` component

Comment: Is this still logging undefined in Sidebar? `console.log("user playlist from sidebar.js", playlists);`

If you updated your code, will you update your description so we can see the changes

Comment: @BankBuilder no it is solved now...All i had to do is add `return`  before `<SidebarOption title={list.name} />;` .. As I'm using curly braces that's why I forgot to add `return`, At first I thought arrow function automatically returns something but I was wrong. As I was using `{}` so I had to add `return` in front of the statement. I've updated the `Sidebar.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is add return before `<SidebarOption title={list.name} />;` .. As I'm using curly braces that's why I forgot to add `return`, At first I thought the arrow function automatically returns something but I was wrong. As I was using `{}` so I had to add return in front of the statement. I've updated the `Sidebar.js`